# Find the point of intersection of 3 planes

Tags: vectors

Plane 1: $(-2x+7y -5z) = 8$

Plane 2: $(x-y) = 1$

Plane 3: $(5x+5y+9z)=-32$

I have to find the point of intersection of these 3 planes. Plane 3 is perpendicular to the 2 other planes.

Comment: You have three equations with three unknowns. Solve the system.

Comment: It's just solving linear equations by Gaussian elimination. Incidentally plane 3 is not perpendicular to plane 1.

Comment: If plane 3 is 5x+5y-9z =22 , is it perpencular to plane 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying the second equation by $2$ and adding to the first we get $$5y-5z=10$$ or (dividing by $5$)
$$y-z=2$$
multiplying the first equation by $5$ and the third by $2$ and adding we get
$$45y-7z=-24$$
multiplying the first equation above by $-7$ and adding to the second we get
$$38y=-114$$ or $$y=-3$$
can you finish?

Comment: I meant the equations in my post.